# Is there a way to change a target div's text when hovering over other div's using css only?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with html, css and php to make a row of image divs. I want to be able to hover over the images individually and have their description text display in a separate div (DivB) in the next row below.

This is the basic structure:

```
<div class="pic1">Display Picture 1 here</div>
  <div class="pic2">Display Picture 2 here</div>
  <div class="pic3">Display Picture 3 here</div>
  <div class="pic4">Display Picture 4 here</div>
<div class="text-info">Description Text for all above div's displayed here on hover of above div's.</div>
```

In other words:

If I hover over Image 1, image 1's description is shown in DivB.
If I hover over Image 2, image 2's description is shown in DivB.
If I hover over Image 3, image 3's description is shown in DivB.
Etc.

Parameters:

1. How do I do this as a css-only solution?
2. No Jquery.
3. I may have to do this with up to 1,000 images, so minimizing the code without repeating functions (a thousand times), by using something like arrays or loops would be very valuable.

I have a working solution using Jquery and css as a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/70chk8yn/

I've looked up numerous css examples and fiddles, but not found any close enough to this example for me to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu2qbwar/)

```
#text-info:after {
  content: "Description Text for all above div's displayed here on hover of above div's.";
}

.pic1:hover~#text-info:after {
  content: 'The description for picture 1.';
}

.pic2:hover~#text-info:after {
  content: 'Picture 2 description.';
}

.pic3:hover~#text-info:after {
  content: 'The description for picture 3.';
}

.pic4:hover~#text-info:after {
  content: "Picture 4's description.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it using `CSS` only for a long list of images and descriptions without the code getting long.

So, you can set each description inside a `p` and make each `hover` in the `images` show a different `p` within the description `div`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="pic">Display Picture 1 here</div>
<div class="pic">Display Picture 2 here</div>
<div class="pic">Display Picture 3 here</div>
<div class="pic">Display Picture 4 here</div>
<div class="text-info">
  <p>Description 1</p>
  <p>Description 2</p>
  <p>Description 3</p>
  <p>Description 4</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pic {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}    
.pic:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
.text-info {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
}
.text-info p {
  display: none;
}
.pic:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .text-info p:nth-of-type(1),
.pic:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .text-info p:nth-of-type(2),
.pic:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .text-info p:nth-of-type(3),
.pic:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ .text-info p:nth-of-type(4)
{
  display: block;
}
```

The concern now is: how to repeat this in `CSS` multiple times for a lot of images and descriptions?

Well, in this case you may use `PHP`, `JavaScript` or a `CSS preprocessor` like `SASS` to create the `style`.
You just have to repeat `.pic:nth-of-type(n):hover ~ .text-info p:nth-of-type(n)` as many times as necessary, where `n` starts at 1 and the last `n` will be the `length` of images you have.

For example, you have 3 images (and 3 descriptions), the rendered `CSS` will be:

```
.pic:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .text-info p:nth-of-type(1),
.pic:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .text-info p:nth-of-type(2),
.pic:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .text-info p:nth-of-type(3)
{
  display: block;
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Actually you can using the content property

Comment: I know, but you don't need to use `pseudo-elements` either, especially if you want to change a specific `p` element later.

Comment: The op was asking for a css solution, hence the content approach, your approach would have been correct had the op said "I feel like this isn't the right way to do it"

Comment: I understand, but he is using `PHP` to render the images, the same way can be rendering the descriptions. Also, using `pseudo-elements` for content may not be the best choice in most cases, they can not be accessed in DOM.

Comment: Again agreed with the statement and your justification, but the user is clearly asking for a css only approach as stated from his first parameter

Comment: I respect your point, however my interpretation is different: he requested a `CSS` only solution to show the descriptions, basically. And the descriptions content of OP code are in HTML, which reinforces what I understood. But it's alright. It is good to have different answers that in practice solve the problem.

Comment: Agreed on this point, anyways have a great and productive day ahead friend

Comment: Thank you Azametzin and Immortal Dude. Both of your interpretations are valid and helpful to me. I can see myself using both someday down the road. Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function  pic(x){
    document.querySelector(".txt-info").innerHTML=x.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.txt-info {
            height: 50px;
            width: 400px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 6px;
            }
        
        .pic{
            height: 30px;
            width: 200px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }
        
        .pic:hover{
            background-color: grey;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="pic" onmouseover="pic(this)">Display Picture 1 here </div>
    <div class="pic" onmouseover="pic(this)">Display Picture 2 here</div>
    <div class="pic" onmouseover="pic(this)">Display Picture 3 here</div>
    <div class="pic" onmouseover="pic(this)">Display Picture 4 here</div>
    <div class="txt-info"> Description Text for all above div's displayed here on hover of above div's.</div>
</body>
```

You just have to used only one class .pic and onmouseover="pic(this)" for all your div that have content and other class .txt-info for displaying all content in common div (without jquery and not css)

Comment: Again, how is this a) different from the previously posted answer b) a css only approach?

Comment: No used of jquery and not also apply many css (only javascript function). Suppose there is 1,000 images then have to write 1000 different css.

Comment: This conflicts with his first requirement of only css

Comment: I have tried to avoid css part and write only one function in javascript  (for minimal code)

Comment: Hi Rishkesh Pal. Although your solution does use a minimal amount of scripting (which I didn't ask for), I tested it and it works. I love the fact that your solution is lightweight and elegant. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @user10478903 you can also approve his answer. rishikesh pal's answer also valid.